# Unsquashfs fails partways with gzip error code -5

Tags: linux, file-format, decompress

I have been trying to unsquash a system.sfs file in order to modify the directories. however, `unsquashfs system.sfs` returns the following output:

```
Parallel unsquashfs: Using 8 processors
1 inodes (16000 blocks) to write

[===========================================|                                        ]  8386/16000  52%
gzip uncompress failed with error code -5
[=============================================================-                      ] 11906/16000  74%
```

And it keeps hanging there. After I force the termination of the unsquashing process, I get a single `system.img` file, however, it is partial and can't be processed as a valid archive.
I have tried following the advice in [this article](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/unsquashfs-fails), none of the tools helped solve the problem.
`hexdump system.img` doesn't produce any unusual output (except the address where it stopped maybe [0x4CCA0000]?):

```
4cc9ff30  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 03 7d 95 99 9d a1  |@..........}....|
4cc9ff40  a5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 04 74 24 2c 00 00 00  |..........t$,...|
4cc9ff50  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  05 77 34 3c 00 00 00 00  |.........w4<....|
4cc9ff60  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06  7e 95 9d 00 00 00 00 00  |........~.......|
4cc9ff70  00 00 00 00 00 00 80 80  2a 3a 6a 7a 8a 9b 00 00  |........*:jz....|
4cc9ff80  00 00 00 00 00 82 82 2a  3a 6a 7a 8a 9b 00 00 00  |.......*:jz.....|
4cc9ff90  00 00 00 00 81 81 32 72  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |......2r........|
4cc9ffa0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
4cc9ffb0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 06 10 30 78  |..............0x|
4cc9ffc0  99 50 00 00 00 00 00 01  01 01 01 02 02 03 03 03  |.P..............|
4cc9ffd0  04 04 04 05 05 06 06 06  0a 0a 0a 0b 0b 0c 0c 0c  |................|
4cc9ffe0  07 07 07 07 08 08 09 09  09 0d 0d 0d 0e 0e 0f 0f  |................|
4cc9fff0  0f 04 04 04 05 05 06 06  06 10 10 04 04 04 05 05  |................|
4cca0000
```

When I issued `binwalk system.img`, the output looked rather usual until the end of the file, which produced:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1062442       0x10362A        Unix path: /../gm200/acr/bl.bin
1062698       0x10372A        Unix path: /../gm200/acr/ucode_load.bin
1062954       0x10382A        Unix path: /../gm200/acr/ucode_unload.bin
1063466       0x103A2A        Unix path: /../gm200/gr/fecs_bl.bin
1063978       0x103C2A        Unix path: /../gm200/gr/fecs_inst.bin
1064490       0x103E2A        Unix path: /../gm200/gr/gpccs_bl.bin
.
.
.
1045975763    0x3E5852D3      Unix path: /android/internal/net/NetworkStatsFactory
1045982563    0x3E586D63      Unix path: /android/internal/os/Zygote
1046052864    0x3E598000      ELF, 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV)
1046110595    0x3E5A6183      mcrypt 2.2 encrypted data, algorithm: blowfish-448, mode: CBC, keymode: 8bit
1046294454    0x3E5D2FB6      POSIX tar archive, owner user name: "SKIP_PADDING FAILED at line %d", owner group name: "hunk header at %d has invalid ty"
```

I couldn't find any information whatsoever about the aforementioned issues.
Any insights on how I can address the problem?